# Why does this EF query return no result in spite of including a Count in the result?

Tags: entity-framework-6

Why does EF generate a query such that the following generates no result rows and First throws an exception.

```
IQueryable<EntityName> repo = GetQuery<EntityName>();
IQueryable<EntityName> query = repo.Where(x => x.Discriminator == 1);
var result = repo.Select(x => new
{
    TotalRecords = query.Count(),
    Results = query.Skip(request.Skip).Take(request.Take).ToList()
}).First();
```

This trick allows me to run more than one query under a single database call in EF; I make the call for an arbitrary repository `repo`, and return a new object where each property is a subquery.  This works as long as there are records in the `query` IQueryable.  However, I was surprised to discover that when there are no records in `query`, nothing is returned (i.e. query.Count() is not included in the result). I thought that such a query should produce a result row even if there were no entities in `query`, since it involves a Count(), but it returns nothing. I suspect this has something to do with EF having to generate a single flat result set under the hood.

Comment: It doesn't matter what is inside the `Select`, the result count is always the same as the input set. The `First` (or `Take(1)`) could just limit it to max 1, i.e. 0 or 1. This is basically SQL query behavior, not EF.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that `Count` method always returns a value, but the problem with your trick is that it's a part of an outer `select` query (`repo.Select(x => ...`), so the cardinality of the result set is controlled by the number of the records contained in the outer query `repo` - when it's empty, the result will be empty, hence the `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` and the subqueries inside will not be executed at all.

Different databases have different mechanisms of solving such issue - for instance, Oracle is using a special single record table called `dual`, SQL Server allows `SELECT` without `FROM` etc. But since EF is generic, it cannot use any of those (well, technically it could, if the whole thing is abstracted in a standard way and the actual implementation is delegated to the actual provider, but it's not done).

Still LINQ provides a way (supported by EF) to force a set to return at least 1 record by using the `DefaultIfEmpty` method. It should be applied on outer query before the `Select` operator:

```
var result = repo.DefaultIfEmpty().Select(x => ...
```

Now since the subqueries are totally unrelated to `x`, you can eliminate the db table used to produce the single outer result by using:

```
var result = repo.Where(_ => false).DefaultIfEmpty().Select(x => ...
```

Here the `repo` could be any `IQueryable<T>` as soon as it originates from the `DbContext` to get the correct `IQueryProvider`.